# Python 3 Enumeration List Value doesn't support membership test

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, enumeration

```
from enum import IntEnum
from typing import List
class EnumClass(IntEnum):
   A = 1
   B = 2

   @staticmethod
   def listofconditions() -> 'List[EnumClass]':
      return [EnumClass.A.numerator, \
              EnumClass.B.numerator]


if 1 in EnumClass.listofconditions:
    pass
```

yields:

```
[pylint]:E1135 Value 'EnumClass.listofconditions' doesn't support membership test
```

(I posted this for others Googling a solution to this cryptic message in order to makes sense of it. Solution to follow)

Comment: I think you mean `List[EnumClass]` for the return type hint.

Comment: It's not *that* cryptic an error message; you defined a method but didn't call it.

Comment: So why vote to close something when Googling 'Value doesn't support membership test' doesn't yield an answer. Never quite got that.

Comment: @chepner - so why doesn't message read more along the lines did you mean a method. It's the cryptic nature of the message that made me field this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change code to:

```
if 1 in EnumClass.listofconditions():
```